# Creating a python program that scrapes file from a website

Tags: python, html, download

This is what I have so far

```
import urllib
Champions=["Aatrox","Ahri","Akali","Alistar","Amumu","Anivia","Annie","Ashe","Azir","Blitzcrank","Brand","Braum","Caitlyn","Cassiopeia","ChoGath","Corki","Darius","Diana","DrMundo","Draven","Elise","Evelynn","Ezreal","Fiddlesticks","Fiora","Fizz","Galio","Gangplank","Garen","Gnar","Gragas","Graves","Hecarim","Heimerdinger","Irelia","Janna","JarvanIV","Jax","Jayce","Jinx","Kalista","Karma","Karthus","Kassadin","Katarina","Kayle","Kennen","KhaZix","KogMaw","LeBlanc","LeeSin","Leona","Lissandra","Lucian","Lulu","Lux","Malphite","Malzahar","Maokai","MasterYi","MissFortune","Mordekaiser","Morgana","Nami","Nasus","Nautilus","Nidalee","Nocturne","Nunu","Olaf","Orianna","Pantheon","Poppy","Quinn","Rammus","RekSai","Renekton","Rengar","Riven","Rumble","Ryze","Sejuani","Shaco","Shen","Shyvana","Singed","Sion","Sivir","Skarner","Sona","Soraka","Swain","Syndra","Talon","Taric","Teemo","Thresh","Tristana","Trundle","Tryndamere","TwistedFate","Twitch","Udyr","Urgot","Varus","Vayne","Veigar","VelKoz","Vi","Viktor","Vladimir","Volibear","Warwick","Wukong","Xerath","XinZhao","Yasuo","Yorick","Zac","Zed","Ziggs","Zilean","Zyra"]
currentCount=0
while currentCount < len(Champions):
    urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/"+Champions[currentCount]+ "/Recommended/"+Champions[currentCount]+"_lane_scrape.json","C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\ " +Champions[currentCount]+ "\ "+Champions[currentCount]+ "_lane_scrape.json")
    currentCount+=1
```

What the program is meant to do is to use the list and the currentCount to get the champion, then it goes to the website e.g for "Aatrox" http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/Aatrox/Recommended/Aatrox_lane_scrape.json, then it downloads and stores the file in the folder LolFlavor/Aatrox/Aatrox_lane_scrape.json in this case.

The bit which is Aatrox changes depending on the champion.
Can anyone help me to get it to work?

EDIT: CURRENT CODE WITH VALUE ERROR:

```
import json
import os
import requests
Champions=["Aatrox","Ahri","Akali","Alistar","Amumu","Anivia","Annie","Ashe","Azir","Blitzcrank","Brand","Braum","Caitlyn","Cassiopeia","ChoGath","Corki","Darius","Diana","DrMundo","Draven","Elise","Evelynn","Ezreal","Fiddlesticks","Fiora","Fizz","Galio","Gangplank","Garen","Gnar","Gragas","Graves","Hecarim","Heimerdinger","Irelia","Janna","JarvanIV","Jax","Jayce","Jinx","Kalista","Karma","Karthus","Kassadin","Katarina","Kayle","Kennen","KhaZix","KogMaw","LeBlanc","LeeSin","Leona","Lissandra","Lucian","Lulu","Lux","Malphite","Malzahar","Maokai","MasterYi","MissFortune","Mordekaiser","Morgana","Nami","Nasus","Nautilus","Nidalee","Nocturne","Nunu","Olaf","Orianna","Pantheon","Poppy","Quinn","Rammus","RekSai","Renekton","Rengar","Riven","Rumble","Ryze","Sejuani","Shaco","Shen","Shyvana","Singed","Sion","Sivir","Skarner","Sona","Soraka","Swain","Syndra","Talon","Taric","Teemo","Thresh","Tristana","Trundle","Tryndamere","TwistedFate","Twitch","Udyr","Urgot","Varus","Vayne","Veigar","VelKoz","Vi","Viktor","Vladimir","Volibear","Warwick","Wukong","Xerath","XinZhao","Yasuo","Yorick","Zac","Zed","Ziggs","Zilean","Zyra"]
for champ in Champions:
    os.makedirs("C:\\Users\\Jay\\Desktop\\LolFlavor\\{}\\Recommended".format(champ), exist_ok=True)
    with open(r"C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}\Recommended\{}_lane_scrape.json".format(champ,champ),"w") as f:
        r = requests.get("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/{}/Recommended/{}_lane_scrape.json".format(champ,champ))
        json.dump(r.json(),f)
    with open(r"C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}\Recommended\{}_jungle_scrape.json".format(champ,champ),"w") as f:
        r = requests.get("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/{}/Recommended/{}_jungle_scrape.json".format(champ,champ))
        json.dump(r.json(),f)
    with open(r"C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}\Recommended\{}_support_scrape.json".format(champ,champ),"w") as f:
        r = requests.get("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/{}/Recommended/{}_support_scrape.json".format(champ,champ))
        json.dump(r.json(),f)
    with open(r"C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}\Recommended\{}_aram_scrape.json".format(champ,champ),"w") as f:
        r = requests.get("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/{}/Recommended/{}_aram_scrape.json".format(champ,champ))
        json.dump(r.json(),f)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import  requests

Champions=["Aatrox","Ahri","Akali","Alistar","Amumu","Anivia","Annie","Ashe","Azir","Blitzcrank","Brand","Braum","Caitlyn","Cassiopeia","ChoGath","Corki","Darius","Diana","DrMundo","Draven","Elise","Evelynn","Ezreal","Fiddlesticks","Fiora","Fizz","Galio","Gangplank","Garen","Gnar","Gragas","Graves","Hecarim","Heimerdinger","Irelia","Janna","JarvanIV","Jax","Jayce","Jinx","Kalista","Karma","Karthus","Kassadin","Katarina","Kayle","Kennen","KhaZix","KogMaw","LeBlanc","LeeSin","Leona","Lissandra","Lucian","Lulu","Lux","Malphite","Malzahar","Maokai","MasterYi","MissFortune","Mordekaiser","Morgana","Nami","Nasus","Nautilus","Nidalee","Nocturne","Nunu","Olaf","Orianna","Pantheon","Poppy","Quinn","Rammus","RekSai","Renekton","Rengar","Riven","Rumble","Ryze","Sejuani","Shaco","Shen","Shyvana","Singed","Sion","Sivir","Skarner","Sona","Soraka","Swain","Syndra","Talon","Taric","Teemo","Thresh","Tristana","Trundle","Tryndamere","TwistedFate","Twitch","Udyr","Urgot","Varus","Vayne","Veigar","VelKoz","Vi","Viktor","Vladimir","Volibear","Warwick","Wukong","Xerath","XinZhao","Yasuo","Yorick","Zac","Zed","Ziggs","Zilean","Zyra"]

for champ in Champions:
    r = requests.get("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/{}/Recommended/{}_lane_scrape.json".format(champ,champ))
    print(r.json())
```

If you want to save each to a file. `dump` the json.

```
import json
import simplejson 

for champ in Champions:
    with open(r"C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}_lane_scrape.json".format(champ),"w") as f:
        try:
            r = requests.get("http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/{}/Recommended/{}_lane_scrape.json".format(champ, champ))
            json.dump(r.json(),f)
        except simplejson.scanner.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(e.r.url)
```

The error is from `404 - File or directory not found` as one of you calls fails so there is no valid json to decode.
The offending url is:

```
u'http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/Wukong/Recommended/Wukong_lane_scrape.json'
```

which if you try in your browser will also give you a 404 error. That is caused by the fact there is no user `Wukong` which can be confirmed by opening `http://www.lolflavor.com/champions/Wukong/` in your browser

There is no need to index the list using a while loop. simply iterate over the list items directly and use str.format to pass the variables into the url. Also make sure you use raw string `r` for the file path when using `\'s` as  they have a special meaning in python they are using to escape characters so `\n` or `\r` etc.. in your paths would cause problems. You can also use `/` or  escape using `\\`.

Comment: Hi, I got an error Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jay/Desktop/lolflavor scraper.py", line 3, in <module>
    import requests
ImportError: No module named 'requests'

Comment: Pip install requests. You wont regret installing requests.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to change the directory to with open(r"C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}\Recommended\{}_lane_scrape.json".format(champ),"w") as f: but I get error tuple index is out of range

Comment: You only have one champ

Comment: Thank you, I sorted that out now, sorry for being annoying but can you help with os.makedirs? I have to make the folder.

I tried this:

path=("C:\Users\Jay\Desktop\LolFlavor\{}\Recommended".format(champ))
    os.makedirs(path)

I get Unicode Error Unicode Escape

Comment: Make sure to put r before the path

Comment: I tried adding more lines now, for the different roles:
I'll add it to the original how the code is now, but I get a ValueError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0) now from the json decoder

Comment: Thanks again, sorted.